# How to exactly locate the picture in the bottom right corner of the frame?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I came across a problem while using the pgf package.Every time I want to change the coordinates,the picture disappears.I don't know why.Here are my codes and outputs.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Berlin}
}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{pgf}

\def\EE{\mathscr{E}}\def\FF{\mathscr{F}}
\def\IP{\mathbb{P}}\def\IE{\mathbb{E}}
\def\BB{\mathscr{B}}
\def\IR{\mathbb{R}}
\def\ss{\mathsf{s}}
\def\df{\mathrm{d}}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]
{bg.jpg}}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white,bg=black}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Markov processes and Dirichlet forms}
\begin{itemize}
\item $(T_t)\leftrightarrows (L,D(L)\rightleftarrows (\EE,\FF)$
\item $0\le T_tu\le 1$ for any $0\le u\le 1$ $\rightleftarrows$ $(\EE,\FF)$ 
is Markov
\end{itemize}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(0,0)}{\pgfbox[left,base]{\pgfimage[width=1cm]{logo.jpg}}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But if I change the coordinates,for example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Berlin}
}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{pgf}

\def\EE{\mathscr{E}}\def\FF{\mathscr{F}}
\def\IP{\mathbb{P}}\def\IE{\mathbb{E}}
\def\BB{\mathscr{B}}
\def\IR{\mathbb{R}}
\def\ss{\mathsf{s}}
\def\df{\mathrm{d}}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]
{bg.jpg}}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white,bg=black}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Markov processes and Dirichlet forms}
\begin{itemize}
\item $(T_t)\leftrightarrows (L,D(L)\rightleftarrows (\EE,\FF)$
\item $0\le T_tu\le 1$ for any $0\le u\le 1$ $\rightleftarrows$ $(\EE,\FF)$ 
is Markov
\end{itemize}
\pgfputat{\pgfxy(0,1cm)}{\pgfbox[left,base]{\pgfimage[width=1cm]{logo.jpg}}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It became like this.

[image]

I have no idea how it came out like this.Can anybody answers me?Thank you so much!

Comment: It seems `\pgfputat` is not the mainstream anymore. Would you like to switch a newer syntax: `\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node at(current page.south east)[left above]{\includegraphics{...}};`?

Comment: @Symbol1So sorry that I'm a beginner in beamer,so I can't exactly understand your advice.Are your suggestion like this? < \pgfputat{\pgfxy(0,-1cm)}{\pgfbox[left,base]{\pgfimage[width=1cm]{logo.jpg}}}\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\>

Comment: @Symbol1 Sorry I didn't use the right format in the comment.By the time I knew how to ise the code format in the comment,5 minutes had passed,

Comment: No. The suggestion is to use the syntax @Symbol1 gave ***instead of*** the syntax you used, which is not generally used any longer. Doing stuff with the lower level PGF layer is more complicated for the end-user than using the Ti*k*Z layer, which is designed to be more user-friendly. Also, use of `\pgfimage` is not recommended even by the PGF author. Unless you cannot use `\includegraphics`, it is better to use `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Note that you need to ***compile twice*** for images placed in this way to end up in their proper positions.

Comment: Don't load: `color`, `hyperref`, **Don't say `\def\<macro name>`** unless you really know what you are doing and why you are doing it. If you aren't sure whether you know what you're doing, believe me, you don't. No offence meant, but if you are writing `\def\ss` then you don't know what you are doing and should not be using `\def`.